# Rails ignores the default date format after upgrading from 6.1 to 7.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date-formatting, ruby-on-rails-7

Our application previously defined the default date format as `DD/MM/YYYY` in `config/application.rb` like so:

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = '%d/%m/%Y'
```

This worked as expected in Rails 6.1, but after upgrading to Rails 7.0 it now appears to be ignored by `.to_s`:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 7.0.2.2)
3.0.1 :001 > Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default]
 => "%d/%m/%Y" 
3.0.1 :002 > Date.new(2022, 12, 31).to_s
 => "2022-12-31"
3.0.1 :003 > Date.new(2022, 12, 31).to_fs
 => "31/12/2022"
```

How can I have `.to_s` implement this behaviour in Rails 7.0+?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feature was [deprecated in Rails 7](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/de7c495209811f8f918fa9f915e64df61a6080c1/guides/source/7_0_release_notes.md#deprecations-8). You can turn it back on with `config.active_support.disable_to_s_conversion`

> Deprecate passing a format to #to_s in favor of #to_fs in Array, Range, Date, DateTime, Time, BigDecimal, Float and, Integer.
>
> This deprecation is to allow Rails application to take advantage of a Ruby 3.1 optimization that makes interpolation of some types of objects faster.
>
> New applications will not have the #to_s method overridden on those classes, existing applications can use config.active_support.disable_to_s_conversion.

Comment: It seems odd that this wasn't mentioned in the "Upgrading from Rails 6.1 to Rails 7.0" section of the [Rails upgrade guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html); I'll have to remember to also check the [release notes](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/7_0_release_notes.html) page in the future.

Comment: @GoBusto I agree, this is a concerning change. Would you report the lack of a mention in the guide as a bug, please?

Comment: This approach did not work for me. @GoBusto, did it work for you?

Comment: @Nicholas Weber In my case, there were only one or two places where this was relevant, so I simply changed the code to avoid this problem.

Comment: @GoBusto I've been working on upgrading to Rails 7.0 at my company and this "documentation" (much of it doesn't even qualify for that term) is atrocious.  So many of the new framework defaults aren't even explained.  They seem to assume you're a staff full stack engineer with at least 30 years of experience (yes, Rails came out in 2004, that's my point) and are an expert in Rails.

Answer (score 13):

Bear in mind, `config.active_support.disable_to_s_conversion` doesn't restore the original functionality of `to_s` on a date. Your dates will not hit the default formatter you have configured.

I'm not sure if any of this is intentional.

You have two options to fix this:

1. Find everywhere you need your date to display in your selected format and add `.to_fs`. This is probably the more correct way to fix this.
2. Or do what we did and defy the wishes of the rails devs. Add an initializer that overrides the `.to_s` method on a date because going to over 9000 different locations to add `.to_fs` to each date display in your code is just too much for you to think about right now.

`./config/initializers/date_format_fix.rb`

```rb
require "date"

class Date
  def to_s(format = :default)
    if formatter = DATE_FORMATS[format]
      if formatter.respond_to?(:call)
        formatter.call(self).to_s
      else
        strftime(formatter)
      end
    else
      to_default_s
    end
  end
end
```

The same can be done with `Time` and `DateTime`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @scilence answer, same solution for datetime column from the database will look like this:

```
module ActiveSupport
  class TimeWithZone
    def to_s(format = :default)
      if formatter = Time::DATE_FORMATS[format]
        if formatter.respond_to?(:call)
          formatter.call(self).to_s
        else
          strftime(formatter)
        end
      else
        to_default_s
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

In this case for rails 7, used in form:

```
f.input_field :period_from, label: false, class: 'form-control',
            data: { behaviour: 'datepicker', language: I18n.locale }, value: f.object.period_from&.to_fs
```