# How to set the default date and time formats in Ruby on Rails 7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-7

When the default date format is set in rails 7, I keep getting the following deprecation warning when calling the `to_s` method:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: Using a :default format for Date#to_s is
> deprecated. Please use Date#to_fs instead.

I set the default date format in an initializer, `config/initializers/date_formats.rb`, as:

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%d/%m-%Y"
```

When the default format (the line above) is removed, `to_s` works as expected, without any warnings, with the default format as `%Y-%m-%d`.

When I call `to_fs` instead, as the deprecation warning tells me to, it prints the default format (`%Y-%m-%d`). I therefore want to change the default format for `to_fs` to `%d/%m-%Y`. Normally I would do that in the initializer (add the line above again), which works fine, but it only reintroduces the deprecation warning when `to_s` is called.

So where do I set the default date format properly in rails 7? I.e. how can I set a default date format for `to_fs` without introducing a deprecation warning for `to_s`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the default format in `config/locales`. For example

```yaml
en:
  date:
    formats:
      default: "%d/%m-%Y"
```

However, without seeing the exact deprecation message this might not be a solution to your problem.

See also question [Rails ignores the default date format after upgrading from 6.1 to 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71177165/rails-ignores-the-default-date-format-after-upgrading-from-6-1-to-7-0) - it might be the same issue you have.

Comment: Updated my question. It is the same problem as the question you suggested, and I have solved it by typing 'to_fs' everywhere (solution 1). But I still need to call 'to_s', and I still need to change the default format for 'to_fs'. I.e. I cannot figure out how to change the default date format without causing any problems with 'to_s'.